# import React is not functioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a small javascript app using React, but I have an error on the first line where importing react.  The error reads: `Missing ; before statement: import React from 'react';`

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

const styles = {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    textAlign: 'center'  
};

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
       return {
             <div>
                <ul>
                </ul>
             </div>
       }
   }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you build your app ?

Comment: How are you including this JavaScript in your page? Is it being processed/bundled, or are you using a script tag?

Comment: I am using a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

check if this works, you can't return jsx in {} , that would return an object in render.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

const styles = {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    textAlign: 'center'  
};

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
       return (
             <div>
                <ul>
                </ul>
             </div>
       )
   }
}
```